# Http/2 site will not load on Safari 9 Only - Loads okay on Chrome, IE, Edge, Firefox

Tags: apache, encryption, nginx, https, http2

I have a site I host that was recently upgraded to HTTP/2 that runs a apache 2.4 / nginx 1.9.5 reverse proxy setup.   The site loads fine of every modern browser and OS I have tested besides Safari 9.  On Safari 9 the web page just times out after multiple minutes to the custom 500 error page.  The issue is repeatable as I tested it on 3 different Macs with Safari 9 and the same thing happened in all 3 places.  No errors appear in apache or nginx error logs.   Access log show the request repeated over and over from the Safari browser all with http status 200, and again the Safari browser just shows the load bar until it times out.  I have also tried to have Safari just access a phpinfo() file with no other code and the same thing happens.

Comment: Check your cipher-suites!

Comment: ssl ciphers are: "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";

Comment: Also, incase it matters, I the ciphers were not changed during the switchover to http/2.  None of the config was besides the lines to enable HTTP/2.   Before we were running standard HTTPS with SPDY with the same ciphers.

Comment: Yes, but HTTP/2 is more strict  with the ciphers. Check an HTTP/2 enabled website that works in Safari (e.g. shimmercat.com) using SSL Qualys to get the list of ciphers right. You can also check the [black list](http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.A), but it is rather long and doesn't tell you what to do.

Comment: Well comparing SSL qualys their are some different ciphers being used, but what stood out more to me was the minor difference in the Elliptic curve part of the Handshake Simulation for Safari 9, could that be the issue?

thephonecaseplace.com Handshake: "Safari 9 / OS X 10.11  R RSA 2048 (SHA256)   TLS 1.2 > h2 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384   ECDH secp256r1  FS"

shimmercat.com Handshake: "Safari 9 / OS X 10.11  R RSA 2048 (SHA256)   TLS 1.2 > h2  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384   ECDH secp521r1  FS"  so secp256r1 vs secp521r1

Comment: Most likely that is the difference. My suggestion is that you try to translate that list of ciphers to your server, it works well in common-browsers. And it took me a lot of iterations to get it right :-( ....

Comment: Yeah same here, when I made mine it took a few tries to get the A+ rating on ssl quals.  I hope I dont have to loose the A+ for Safari on HTTP2 when it worked great with 1.1 and SPDY

Comment: @dsign Could you possibly share your SSLCipherSuite line from your conf from shimmercat.com for testing?

Comment: For what is worth, it's here: https://github.com/shimmercat/second-transfer/blob/master/cbits/enable_tls.cpp#L89 .

Comment: Nice code, thank you.  Unfortunatly Haskell is new to me.  I had noticed your server header showed Apache as your web server and I had mistakenly thought you may of had a similiar setup with openssl and Apache so I could borrow your SSLCipherSuite line from the Apache conf to replace mine for testing, as I had trouble manually converting your ciphers from the online SSL checkers to a compayable openssl cipher spec.  Thanks again for posting it though, just not something I can use to test if the cipher suite is my issue.  I will keep investigating as much as I can.  If you have any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

check your ssl protocols in ssl params. it happens by the modern browsers to use the ssl procols TLSv1.1 and later. but the safari taking the ssl protolcs such as TLSv1. so replace your ssl params in your ssl configuration and place this code and restart your server

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/sslsnippet/dhparam.pem; 
ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5:!aNULL;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
```

And also find your dhparam.pem, then place the path instead of i mentioned in the above code

Comment: Safari 9 supports TLS 1.2. Please don't suggest to use anything less like TLS 1.0 or 1.1

Comment: If you are using the safari 5 series browser, it only support with TLSv1 series. I wrote this for support all series of old safari browsers

Answer (score 0):

We were seeing very similar issues, where various versions of Safari 10 would make the same request every 30 ms or so, for hundreds of times. The server would serve each response successfully.

Our setup was different - IIS with Node.js, through IISNode - but I think the general idea may be the same. The Node.js app would receive the request via http (so HTTP/1) and automatically include the response header "Connection". IIS would include that header in the response to Safari over HTTP/2. Safari would reject the forbidden "Connection" header and retry.

I solved this by manually removing the implicit "Connection" header in the Node.js app. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72434880/10229666